# Criterion for convexity

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation

This is part of the proof of the differential criterion for convexity. $\Delta$ is actually the difference between the cord and the function $f$ at the point $x_0=px+qy$. If we expand $(6.8)$, we can see it is true. I do not see how do we get $(6.9)$, could any one give me some insight? I tried to look at the area, but didn't get it.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We know that $\Delta \ge 0$,

\begin{align}p\int_x^{px+qy}f'(u) \, du &\le q \int_{px+qy}^y f'(u) \, du \\&
\le q\int_{px+qy}^y f'(px+qy) \, du \\ 
&= qf'(px+qy)[y-(px+qy)]\\
&= qf'(px+qy)[py-px] \\
&= pq(y-x)f'(px+qy)\end{align}